# Postsharp 5.0.31.0 in Dot Net Core 2.0 - Cannot find a method named get_Assembly in type System.Reflection.TypeInfo matching the given predicate

Tags: .net-core, postsharp

I am a avid user of PostSharp and I am using their "Essentials" license. I am trying to upgrade my DotNetCore code from 1.1 to 2.0 and PostSharp is no longer working as expected. I created a simple console application that works when it is 1.1 and when I switch to 2.0 it throws an Unhandled exception with the following error

```
 Unhandled exception (5.0.31.0, postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.460798, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot find a method named get_Assembly in type System.Reflection.TypeInfo matching the given predicate.
    at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindMethod(TypeDefDeclaration typeDef, String methodName, BindingOptions bindingOptions, Predicate`1 predicate)
    at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.InstructionWriterExtensions.EmitAssemblyOf(BaseInstructionWriter writer, ITypeSignature type, TargetFramework targetFramework)
    at ^RIeE65/59SwT.^Pzwdu7KO.Emit(InstructionWriter _0, InstructionBlock _1, TypeInitializationClientScopes _2)
    at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.TypeInitializationManager.^m\.QsIzuy.^B00Ft6I1yuz9(WeavingContext _0, InstructionBlock _1)
    at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeWeaver.Weaver.^MNbVhYZw(MethodDefDeclaration _0)
    at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeWeaver.Weaver.Weave()
    at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.TypeInitializationManager.^r4DISfQ8()
    at ^YRTd8AcBbva/.Execute()
    at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
    at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
    at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
    at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
 Context:
 Weaver.WeaveMethod( {PostSharp.ImplementationDetails_84298fea.<>z__a_2.#cctor} ).  ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\cselbert\.nuget\packages\postsharp\5.0.31\build\PostSharp.targets  329
```

The sample code is straight forward enough

```
 using System;
 using PostSharp.Aspects;
 using PostSharp.Serialization;

 namespace ConsoleApp1
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             var aspectTest = new AspectTest();
             aspectTest.ThrowException();
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }

     [PSerializable]
     public sealed class HandleExceptionAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
     {
         public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs eventArgs)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Instance);

             eventArgs.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
         }
     }

     [HandleException]
     public class AspectTest
     {
         public void ThrowException()
         {
             throw new Exception("Throwing Exception");
         }
     }
 }
```

Is there something I am missing? I have even cleared the "C:\ProgramData\Postsharp" folder but nothing is working.

Is this is License Issue? Has anyone else had success with an upgrade to DotNetCore 2.0 from 1.1?

I even uninstalled and re-installed PostSharp 5.0.31.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current 5.0 version of PostSharp looks like it is not compatible with .NET Core 2.0 and .Net Standard 2.0

[Incompatibilities](http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements#incompatibilities)

Comment: Support for .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0 is planned for PostSharp 5.1.